# What does the { all: 'true' } JavaScript code snippet mean exactly?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to JavaScript and would really like to understand this line of code without having to spend time I don't have learning the language.  Can anyone explain exactly what this does?

```
{ all: 'true' }
```

I think that it makes all elements of a list equal to true, but I'm not sure and I'd like a definite answer.  I can't find one online.

Comment: That code evaluates to be an object with one property, named `all` whose value is the string `'true'`. I'd need more context to know what it's actually used for. It certainly isn't a common expression.

Comment: Could you include code to describe how this is used please? At the moment, that single line is just a raw object definition and doesn't necessarily _do_ anything.

Comment: This is very basic stuff and if you don't want to spend time learning the language, please don't post questions like this here. This is a question for Google or a JavaScript tutorial site. In short, you need to take the time to learn the language.

Comment: Actually I can't post the code it's used in as it isn't mine (otherwise I would have done so at the beginning!).  And since I have to learn several languages at once and use them consistently it isn't worth spending hours learning a language when I can ask the question and get an answer in 5 minutes.  It would be a waste of valuable time and resources, and shouldn't be a prerequisite for asking questions.  But thanks to the people who tried to help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ }
```

Two brackets with something in-between, mean an object (as long as the syntax is correct).

```
{ x: y }
```

When you use a syntax like that, it sets the property `x` on the object to value `y`. So `var obj = {x: "value"};` followed by  `obj.x` would give `value`.

```
{ all: "true" }
```

In your case, merely creates a new object with property `all`, which is set to value `true`. You can access that like `obj.all` or `obj["all"]`.

```js
var obj = { all: "true" };

console.log(obj.all);
console.log(obj["all"]);
```

Comment: Hey, that completely answers my question, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

All it means is: an `object` with a property `all` whose value is string `'true'`

Comment: To be precise, the value is the string `'true'` not the boolean value `true`.